Why does Skin friction drag coefficient decrease with Reynolds number for a flat plate?
I have a question: why does the Skin friction coefficient decrease as Reynolds number increases?
Please see the photo below:

Let’s assume we increase Reynolds number by increasing velocity. Higher velocity = thinner boundary layer = higher shear stresses. Should this not increase the skin friction coefficient?

Friction drag is drag coefficient times dynamic pressure. Of course will drag be higher with higher speed, but the coefficient will be smaller. Only the product of coefficient and speed squared will go up!

Given:

$\tau_w$ is the wall shear stress
$q_{\infty}$ is dynamic pressure beyond the outer edge of the boundary layer

Then:

local skin friction coefficient, $c_{f_x} = \frac{\tau_w}{q_{\infty}}$

$q_{\infty}$ is in the denominator and increases more rapidly with Re than $\tau_w$. For example, if the increase in Reynolds number is solely because of a velocity increase, $q_{\infty}$ is proportional to the square of the velocity. Remember, the Reynolds number is just a ratio of inertial to viscous forces.

Thanks for the edits, @DeltaLima.

Thanks for the edits, @ROIMaison.

You're welcome. If you're interested, have a look at this MathJax tutorial to see how to typeset mathematical equations and symbols on StackExchange.


thinner boundary = higher shear stresses $\tau_w$

Should this not increase the skin friction coefficient?
Not if v$^2$ is in the denominator of C$_f$.
But why?  An understanding might come from a comparison with the interaction of high velocity jet plumes with surrounding air.  Although the boundary layer is thinner, the velocity difference is such that less energy is transferred to the surrounding air per unit velocity, hence a lower coefficient.
This may be due to viscosity being less of a factor as Re number increases.  Once the plume slows down, a thicker, more turbulent layer forms.

"Viscosity" of a $gas$ is a bit hard to fathom, but the lessening of effect with increasing Reynolds number may have a lot to do with velocity.  As the moving surface pulls one air molecule, it will start to pull the next one, then the next one.  (Almost as if they were connected with rubber bands)  If the surface is near the first molecule for a shorter period of time, less surrounding movement (turbulence) will occur.

Please note that that plot should be used in a different way: if you look carefully, the label of the x-axis is $Re_x$ where the "$_x$" actually means: "the local Reynolds number as measured from the leading edge - the "$x$" - of a flat plate".
That plot describes how the local skin friction evolves when moving at a distance $x$ from the leading edge of a flat plate. In particular, it tells us that:

The boundary layer starts laminar by the trailing edge (leftmost part of the plot);
It grows in thickness with a relevant decrease in shear stress and therefore friction (as you've correctly guessed - even if the other way around)
When the distance from the leading edge is such that the relevant $Re_x$ is around $5\times10^5$, then the boundary layer becomes unstable and transitions to turbulent; this transition is accompanied by a jump in the local skin friction (middle line in the plot);
Moving further downstream, the turbulent boundary layer grows again in thickness with a relevant decrease in shear stress and therefore friction (right part of the plot).


Evolution of the boundary layer on a flat plate with the local Reynolds number (picture source)
To get the total skin friction coefficient for a plate of length $L$ you need to integrate that plot from $x=Re_x=0$ (yep, in this case the Reynolds number can be $0$ no matter what the speed is) to $Re_L$ and therefore that result does not depend only on the velocity.

Let’s assume we increase Reynolds number by increasing velocity. Should this not increase the skin friction coefficient?

It should be clear now that the answer is: depends. If the combination of velocity and length is such that the boundary layer remains fully laminar then you are going to get a lower friction than a case where the $Re_x$ is fully turbulent, even if the speed is higher!
